# Deleting from a list list one where list1.a is equal to list2.a with linq

Tags: linq

I have a list List of Accountables  and a list List of Dilutions with a common field Contract.
I need to delete in  List of Accountables all contracts that exist in List of Dilutions and I wanted to do it with Linq.

I've been trying to solve this to no success so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can please you post what you have tried

Comment: If your problem solved by my answer, you could mark it as accepted answer by toggling the check sign in the left hand of answer to green.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
var deletions =
    from a in accountables
    join d in dilutions on a.Contract equals d.Contract into gds
    where gds.Any()
    select a;

foreach (var d in deletions.ToArray())
{
    accountables.Remove(d);
}
```